# Spring function based injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is there any way to inject a spring bean using @Autowired and instead of using a qualifier, using a custom annotation which resolves the bean based on a function and an argument?

For example

```
@Autowired
@FunctionQualifier(method=fetchCorrectBean)
private MyService myService;
```

The fetchCorrectBean is a function which will fetch the bean from the application context and inject it.

Comment: yes it is possible. check this article https://memorynotfound.com/creating-and-configuring-custom-qualifier-annotation/

Comment: Dynamic injection of prototype bean inside a a prototype bean.